# Visual Studio .NET C# executable traces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, trace

i've got a question, is it possible to identify the creator of a .NET assembly, just with traces from VisualStudio within the assembly ?

Or can you even get a kind of unique ID of the creator out of it?

I don't mean the application information like company or description, they can be edited too easily.

Comment: Would the code signing tools suffice?

Comment: Normally they would...
But in this case its a bit different, i want to identify who made this assembly and no the code is not signed, would be too easy i guess.
And even if you would sign, you could create a new keypair and nobody would know its yours...

Comment: remember the difference between code signing and strong names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer based on the fact that the code is not strong named or signed is no**. Ultiamtely the only way would be to use some kind of public authority isseued certificate based code signing approach. And that is say unequivocally (theft aside) that a particular certificate owner signed the code, not that someone wrote the code.

Into the realms of more conjecture perhaps, if the code was written via a unique compiler, then one could possibly work this out. However I cannot see even this being unequivocal as who ran the compiler etc....

Comment: But even if it is strong named, you could not identify someone because you could not assign the public key to one individual(you can generate a new keypair and nobody will know its your), can you?

Comment: that why I use certificate based code signing as the example, not strong naming.

Comment: Yeah i understood that ;)

But i just wanted somebody to approve that my understanding of strong naming is right.

But nevermind all questions solved now.

Thank you